# Bootstrap carousel control's shape shows different between server and localhost

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap3 to working on my home view page in Visual Studio, but the carousel control icon shows different between sever side(looks like square) and localhost(looks normal), is anything I missed? Thank you so much for the help!

I attached the carousel part of my code below:

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicators
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        </ol> -->
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <table id="Report_InvHardCatExpiring-table" class="table table-striped styleTable table-hover" style="border:2px;">
                                    <caption>Hardware expiring 90 days out.</caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#a0bac4">
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvHardwareAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().InvHardwareCatName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvSoftwareAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().CountType)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Report_InvHardwareAggregateCat)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.InvHardwareCatName
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.CountType
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <table id="Report_InvSoftCatExpiring-table" class="table table-striped styleTable table-hover" style="border:2px;">
                                    <caption>Software expiring 90 days out.</caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#a0bac4">
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvSoftwareAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().InvSoftwareCatName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvSoftwareAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().CountType)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Report_InvSoftwareAggregateCat)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.InvSoftwareCatName
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.CountType
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <table id="Report_InvFurnitureCatExpiring-table" class="table table-striped styleTable table-hover" style="border:2px;">
                                    <caption>Furniture expiring 90 days out.</caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#a0bac4">
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvFurnitureAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().InvFurnitureCatName)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvFurnitureAggregateCat.FirstOrDefault().CountType)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Report_InvFurnitureAggregateCat)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.InvFurnitureCatName
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.CountType
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <table id="Report_InvHardware_ByProdTypeByAmount-table" class="table table-striped styleTable table-hover" style="border:2px;">
                                    <caption>Hardware category by cost.</caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#a0bac4">
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvHardware_ByProdTypeByAmount.FirstOrDefault().Name)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvHardware_ByProdTypeByAmount.FirstOrDefault().CountInvProductTypeID)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_InvHardware_ByProdTypeByAmount.FirstOrDefault().SumAmount)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Report_InvHardware_ByProdTypeByAmount)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.Name
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.CountInvProductTypeID
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @item.SumAmountFormatted
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background-image: none;">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background-image: none;">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

What it shows on my server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBXDi.jpg)

What it shows on my localhost:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jTfR.jpg)

Comment: Check the console for errors, I reckon it is on the servers sidde cors is stopping the loading of the icons or something.

Also (if possible) do not use links to images but paste directly into query or copy and paste the actual text (you should be able to copy the icons used and paste them into the question).

Comment: It appears glyphicons are not working properly in the deployed version. From what you posted we have no way of determining why that is.

Comment: Thank you @Slipoch for the suggestion, I will check it out and make the correct format on public questions next time :)

Comment: Thanks for give me a suggestion @tao!